# Calculating the Sum of values in 2 linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

So I got a programming question at an interview recently.

There are 2 linked lists, each node's store a value from 1 through 9 (indicating one index of the number). Hence 123 would be a linked list 1->2->3

The task was to create a function:

`static LinkedListNode getSum(LinkedListNode a, LinkedListNode b)`

that would return the sum of the values in the 2 linked list arguements.

If the array a is: 1->2->3->4

And the array b is: 5->6->7->8

The answer should be: 6->9->1->2

Here is my algorithm:

Go through each node in a and b, get the values as an integer and add them. Create a new linked list with the those values.

Here is the code: It runs with a complexity of O(3n) roughly I assume. Once through each of the array inputs and once to create the output array.

**Any improvements? Better algorithms... or code improvements**

```
public class LinkedListNode {
        LinkedListNode next;
        int value;

    public LinkedListNode(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    static int getValue(LinkedListNode node) {
        int value = node.value;
        while (node.next != null) {
            node = node.next;
            value = value * 10 + node.value;
        }
        return value;
    }

    static LinkedListNode getSum(LinkedListNode a, LinkedListNode b) {
        LinkedListNode answer = new LinkedListNode(0);
        LinkedListNode ans = answer;
        int aval = getValue(a);
        int bval = getValue(b);
        int result = aval + bval;
        while (result > 0) {
            int len = (int) Math.pow((double) 10,
                    (double) String.valueOf(result).length() - 1);
            int val = result / len;
            ans.next = new LinkedListNode(val);
            ans = ans.next;
            result = result - val*len;
            }    
        return answer.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the task was to add numbers where the *decimal digits* are represented as a linked list. You should add that to the question, as it is this is very hard to understand.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, this question already has an [answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19320580/752320) This copy was originally cross-posted at Programmers, and migrated here instead of closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me give it a shot...

```
static LinkedListNode getSum(LinkedListNode a, LinkedListNode b) {  
  //some checks first if any computation will be needed at all
  if(a == null) {
    if(b == null)
      return null;
    else
      return b;
  } else if (b == null)
    return a;

  //initialize the variables
  LinkedListNode stacka = null; 
  LinkedListNode stackb = null;
  LinkedListNode ans = null;
  LinkedListNode temp = null;

  //move the contents of a & b into stacka & stackb respectively at the same time
  //best case is when a & b are of equal size
  //worst case is when the size of a & b are worlds apart.
  while(a != null || b != null){
    if(a != null) {
      if(stacka == null){
        stacka = new LinkedListNode(a.value);
      } else {
        temp = new LinkedListNode(a.value);
        temp.next = stacka;
        stacka = temp;
      }
    }

    if(b != null) {
      if(stackb == null){
        stackb = new LinkedListNode(b.value);
      } else {
        temp = new LinkedListNode(b.value);
        temp.next = stackb;
        stackb = temp;
      }
    }

    if(a != null) a = a.next;
    if(b != null) b = b.next;
  }

  int remainder = 0;
  //just pop off the stack then merge! also, don't forget the remainder~
  while(stacka != null || stackb != null){
    //pop from the top of the stack
    int i = ((stacka == null) ? 0 : stacka.value) + ((stackb == null) ? 0 : stackb.value) + remainder;

    //set the value of the remainder if any as well as the value of i
    remainder = i / 10;
    i %= 10;

    temp = new LinkedListNode(i);
    if(ans == null) {
      ans  = temp;
    } else {
      temp.next = ans;
      ans = temp;
    }
    if(stacka != null) stacka = stacka.next;
    if(stackb != null) stackb = stackb.next;
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Since I didn't use the getValue() function, this should be around O(2n) at best case. 
What I did here was use the LinkedListNode as a stack to temporarily store the nodes while I invert them, then pop the values off one at a time to populate the output LinkedListNode.

Then again, In the end, both algorithms still fall under O(n) so the difference can be negligible.

I'll try to make a recursive version later if I have time.

P.S. Sorry if i didn't add curly braces to some of my if else statements, its hard to tab them using the answer form

Answer (score 1):

The original question is in Java, but here's a very simple Scala solution. It left pads the lists with 0's so that they're the same length. Then, it zips the lists together so that we have a single list of pairs. Finally, it adds the pairs right to left passing along a carry value. (The same way you learned how to add numbers in first grade.) It shows how we can solve problems quickly and with small amounts of code using functional techniques:

```
def add(nums1: List[Int], nums2: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val nums1Size = nums1.size
  val nums2Size = nums2.size
  val maxSize = nums1Size max nums2Size

  val nums1Padded = List.fill(maxSize - nums1Size)(0) ++ nums1
  val nums2Padded = List.fill(maxSize - nums2Size)(0) ++ nums2
  val zipped = nums1Padded.zip(nums2Padded)

  val (result, carry) = zipped.foldRight((List.empty[Int], 0)) { (curr, r) =>
    val sum = curr._1 + curr._2 + r._2
    ((sum % 10) :: r._1, sum / 10)
  }

  if (carry > 0) carry :: result else result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be optimized by constructing the resulting linked list from back-to-front:

```
int aval = getValue(a);
int bval = getValue(b);
int result = aval + bval;
LinkedListNode answer = null;
while (result > 0) {
    int val = result % 10;
    LinkedListNode prev = answer;
    answer = new LinkedListNode(val);
    answer.next = prev;
    result /= 10;
}
if (answer == null) {
    // Assuming you want to return 0 rather than null if the sum is 0
    answer = new LinkedListNode(0);
}
return answer;
```

This avoids the repeated Math.pow calls.

I think the overall algorithm you used should be fastest. One alternative that comes to mind is doing some kind of add-with-carry operation on each pair of digits (i.e. doing the addition "manually"), but that would very likely be slower.

Comment: Doing the carries manually would likely be faster, since you're only adding single digits and 9+9 = 18, meaning you'd only have to test whether it was > 10, and if so subtract 10 and do the carry.  But since we're using a linked list that stores single digits, I don't think it would make a real difference in speed, because it's almost certainly swamped with all those pointer dereferences.

Comment: Well, the main issue performance-wise is that you would need to traverse each list twice, once to get to the least-significant digit, then back again as we add each pair of digits.

Comment: If we altered the problem by having the linked lists store numbers from smallest digit to largest digit, that problem would go away.  That representation would actually make more sense in general as well, at least for a singly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in these types of exercises one is expected to perform the operation without converting into a more common intermediate form first (like an integer).  The next question I would expect to get is, "What if the numbers are 100 digits long?"  Try to solve it using *only* linked lists, although you probably have to reverse the direction of the operands in order to provide a reasonable running time.

Answer (score 0):

First, run through both lists, flipping the directions of the arrows and ending with the final nodes in memory. This is linear time and constant space.

Now you have a pair of linked lists that represent the numbers from their lowest to highest digit. Run through the lists again, creating your new linked list and flipping the arrows back as you go. This is linear time and linear space (for the new list).