# Iteration sum in a linkedlist in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have 3 linked lists, in java with this values:

```
    LinkedList<Double> simTarget = new LinkedList<Double>();
    LinkedList<Double> simSource = new LinkedList<Double>();
    LinkedList<Double> results = new LinkedList<Double>();   

    simTarget.add(0.5);
    simTarget.add(0.1); 
    simTarget.add(1.0); 

    simSource.add(0.5); 
    simSource.add(0.1);
    simSource.add(1.0);
```

I need to perform an iteractive sum in these lists and the results I stored in the "results", for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < simTarget.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < simSource.size(); j++)
    {           
     results.add((simTarget.get(i) + (simSource.get(j) * 0.5)/3));              
    }
}
```

So, this is my problem: with the linkedlist "results" is that I need to perform again a new iteration but with the same values of the simSource, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < simSource.size(); j++)
    {
         System.out.println(results.get(i) + (simSource.get(j) * 0.5)/3);
    }
}
```

this iteration need performing (itself) in "x" times, for example: 70 times or 80 times or 1000 times. And just the values of the "results" linkedlist shall increase.

How to perform and to develop this iteration by `x` times?

Thank you very much.

Comment: linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320580/calculating-the-sum-of-values-in-a-linked-list

Comment: Could I ask what you are doing with the **"*0.5)/3)"**?

Comment: yes... it is a just fixed-point. tks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Double` is both `final` and `immutable`, you will have to encapsulate `Double` in a custom class, 'Value' for example. Then, you will update the `Double` field in the `Value` class each time you do a summation. Therefore, only the object of type `Value` strored in `results` will be updated.

```
for(int x = 0;x< 1000;x++){
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < simSource.size(); j++)
        {
            Value buffer = results.get(i);
            buffer.doubleField += (simSource.get(j) * 0.5)/3;
            //System.out.println(results.get(i) + (simSource.get(j) * 0.5)/3);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, since you are accessing the `LinkedList` by index, it will be better to use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I have 2 questions. 
1) I wrote the class value like this, is it right?
public class Value {
 Value buffer;
 public Value doublefield;
 public Value getBuffer() {
  return buffer;
 }

 public void setBuffer(Value buffer) {
  this.buffer = buffer;
 }


public Value GetField(){
 return buffer;
 
}
}

2) How I print the final results?

Comment: The Value class should be like  public class Value{double doubleField;}  thats it. Keep it simple. To print out the result, just iterate other the `results` `LinkedList` and use the usual `System.out.print`